# How to add borders to all pages, while using Parallel for a mirrored/bilingual text?

Tags: babel, parallel

I'm working on a A6 book that consists of mirrored bilingual text (left page in English, right page in French). In order to achieve this, I'm using Babel and Parallel on a A5 landscape page:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{parallel}
% ...
\begin{document}
\begin{Parallel}[c]{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
% ...
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Once the PDF is generated, I'm splitting all pages in two equal halves, in order to obtain the A6 pages (for printing).

Everything is OK.

However, my goal is to have a border on **all A6** pages:

```
--------    --------
|      |    |      |
|      |    |      |
|      |    |      |
|      |    |      |
|-1-   |    |   -2-|
--------    --------
```

Or, if it's easier, to only have corners on **all A5** pages:

```
--                --
|                  |



|-1-            -2-|
--                --
```

For the actual borders, a repeating image would be nicer, but a doubled line (or something similar) can also work.

I'm not very versed in LaTeX and this is one of my firs projects.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit 1**

An example to help with a complete answer:

```
% original packages
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{parallel}

% code taken from the answer
\countdef\pageno=0
\pagestyle{empty}
\expandafter\def\csname @thehead\endcsname{\twoframes\hss}

\def\twoframes{\vbox to0pt{\offinterlineskip \color{red}
   \kern5mm\hbox{\kern-10mm
   % \rlap{\smash{\includegraphics{something}}}%% try to include graphics here
   \oneframe L\kern2mm
   % \global\advance\pageno by1 %% don't use this if you need the same page number  
   \oneframe R}\vss}}
\def\framed#1#2{\vbox{\hrule height#1
   \hbox{\vrule width#1{\kern1pt\vbox{\kern1pt\hbox{#2}\kern1pt}\kern1pt}\vrule width#1}
   \hrule height#1}}
\def\oneframe#1{\vbox{\framed{1pt}{\framed{.4pt}{\vbox to118mm{}\kern80mm}}
   \kern-8mm
   \moveright10mm\hbox to62mm{\color{black}\hfil-- \the\pageno\ --\if#1L\hfill\fi}
}}

% minimal (parallel) content
\begin{document}

\begin{Parallel}[c]{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{Some sample text 1}
\ParallelRText{Some sample text 2}

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

The above code produces the following three errors on build:

```
! Undefined control sequence.\twoframes ->\vbox to0pt{\offinterlineskip \color{red} \kern 5mm\hbox {\ker... l.32 \end{document}
! Undefined control sequence.\oneframe ...m \moveright 10mm\hbox to62mm{\color{black}\hfil -- \the \page...l.32 \end{document}
! Undefined control sequence.\oneframe ...m \moveright 10mm\hbox to62mm{\color{black}\hfil -- \the \page...l.32 \end{document}
```

**Edit 2**

For a working example, `xcolor` should be loaded (`\usepackage{xcolor}`) - see the *Answer* & comments for a full description .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont' know how do you split the PDF A5 pages to A6 pages but this isn't important. If you need to add page numbers and borders around A6 pages then you can try the following code.

```
\countdef\pageno=0
\pagestyle{empty}
\expandafter\def\csname @thehead\endcsname{\twoframes\hss}

\def\twoframes{\vbox to0pt{\kern5mm\hbox{\kern-10mm\oneframe \kern2mm
   \global\advance\pageno by1\oneframe}\vss}}
\def\oneframe{\vbox{\hrule\hbox to83mm{\vrule height118mm \hfil\vrule}\hrule
   \kern-8mm
   \moveright10mm\hbox to62mm{\hfil-- \the\pageno\ --\ifodd\pageno\hfill\fi}}}
```

All dimensions here are guessed by the experiment only, you can tune them by your requirements.

The code redefines the internal LaTeX macro `\@thehead` as `\twoframes` and this macro draws the frames and page numbers as a \vbox with zero height. You can include a graphics in the \twoframes macro too, of course.

**Edit** The next version prints double red frames, as OP mentioned in comment bellow. You need to load `\usepackage{xcolor}` (or something similar) because `\color{red}` is used here. The corners aren't solved here. This is leaved as simple exercise (for those who know TeX primitives used here) because question includes the requirement: borders **or** corners, no both.

I am not able to answer where to put `\includegraphics` into the `\twoframes` macro because I don't know where the included graphics have to be. I inserted one commented line which is suggestion where to do this.

The same page number is on both pages now. This is another requirement of OP mentioned in the comments.

```
\countdef\pageno=0
\pagestyle{empty}
\expandafter\def\csname @thehead\endcsname{\twoframes\hss}

\def\twoframes{\vbox to0pt{\offinterlineskip \color{red}
   \kern5mm\hbox{\kern-10mm
   % \rlap{\smash{\includegraphics{something}}}%% try to include graphics here
   \oneframe L\kern2mm
   % \global\advance\pageno by1 %% don't use this if you need the same page number  
   \oneframe R}\vss}}
\def\framed#1#2{\vbox{\hrule height#1
   \hbox{\vrule width#1{\kern1pt\vbox{\kern1pt\hbox{#2}\kern1pt}\kern1pt}\vrule width#1}
   \hrule height#1}}
\def\oneframe#1{\vbox{\framed{1pt}{\framed{.4pt}{\vbox to118mm{}\kern80mm}}
   \kern-8mm
   \moveright10mm\hbox to62mm{\color{black}\hfil-- \the\pageno\ --\if#1L\hfill\fi}
}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Three questions: (1) I get the 'Draft' watermark; how to remove it? (2) How to change the width and the color of the border line (e.g., double its current size and red). (3) You've mentioned that one _can include a graphics in the \twoframes macro too_; how to achieve this?

Comment: PS1: For splitting the PDF A5 pages to A6 pages I use [pdfscissors](https://sites.google.com/site/pdfscissors/). PS2: Page numbers aren't necessary; I use the _fancyhdr_ package for this purpose.

Comment: @Yeseanul ad (1) "Draft" watermark isn't generated by my macros. This can be generated by your code hidden from me. (2) This is simple and I can show this if you really need. (3) IMHO, LaTeX uses something like `\includegraphics`. I am no LaTeX user, so I don't know details. PS2: The `fancyhdr` package can be in conflict with my macros! Use only one or the second, no both.

Comment: (1) The behaviour is very odd: without your code I don't get the _draft_; with your code on the first build I don't get the _draft_, I get it only on additional builds. Must be a conflict with some packages, I assume. (2) Yes, please. Also (as a bonus) is it possible to only do the corners, or something similar (e.g., v1: two red lines, or v2: two red lines, one thicker and one thinner, but only in the corners of the pages)? PS: If that's the case, can you please show me how to modify you macro in order to get the same page number on both A6 pages (that are on the same A5 landscape page)?

Comment: Ad (1). Start from the document with "usepackages" mentioned in your question only. And remove aux file. The "Draft" doesn't appear because I did the same and I didn't see this word. Then add *only really needed* packages and see at what time the problem occurs. Ad (2) done. Ad PS: Your sketchs in your question includes pages `-1-  -2-`. This is the reason why I meant that you need this style of page numbering. The second version prints the same page numbers at both pages.

Comment: Well written and elegant answer. Thank you. Ad (1) For testing purposes I'm **only** including packages mentioned in the question (plus the needed `background` package) and your code. The result is that on first build everything is OK; while starting with the second build, the _Draft_ watermark appears. This is not such a big deal (because I can just delete all files and rebuild for the final version), but I'm just intrigued by this behavior. Ad (2) Looks very good. Ad PS: True :-).

Comment: @Yeseanul Ad (1). Of course, `background` package is incompatible with my solution, because my solution is based on the same principle, i.e. on "background" but without using any package. Why do you need to load `background` package? I am sure that for nothing. If something on the background is needed, it is possible to put it by my macros.

Comment: Ad (1) If I'm including only the packages from the input and your code, a `\begin{Parallel} ... \end{Parallel}` statement generates a `Undefined control sequence` error on build. Including the `background` package overcomes this. (Don't know/understand why.)

Comment: @Yeseanul Ad (1) Please, give minimal example where the problem occurs. I did experiment with `parallel` (for testing the solution) and I didn't need any `background` package. I don't believe that you explicitly needs `background`. Without minimal example and without full error message (what control sequence is undefined) I am unable to solve this.

Comment: Ad (1) I've edited the question in order to provide an example and the build errors.

Comment: Add the `\usepackage{xcolor}`. Enlightenment: (A) read full error message: the line is broken at the point `\color{red}`, it means, that the undefined control sequence is `\color`. (B) Read my answer carefully: "You need to load \usepackage{xcolor} (or something similar) because \color{red} is used here.". (C) The `background` package loads the `xcolor` package as dependency. But it adds the new feature: it adds the "Draft" word by default, read the manual of `background` package. You needn't the `background` package.

Comment: Now I understand. Thank you very much for your answer and comments.

Answer (score 3):

you can do this with background package

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper, landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}
\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage[
placement=top,
angle=0,
color=black,
opacity=1,
scale=1,
anchor= below,
position={8cm,1cm}
]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newcount\mt
\begin{document}
\backgroundsetup{contents={%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\mt=\thepage%
\multiply\mt by 2
\node at (16.5cm,-11.5cm) {\the\mt};
\advance\mt by -1
\node at (.5cm,-11.5cm) {\the\mt};
\draw(0,0) rectangle (8cm,-12cm);
\draw(9cm,0) rectangle (17cm,-12cm);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\begin{Parallel}[c]{0.45\textwidth}{0.45\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{\lipsum[1-10]}
\ParallelRText{\lipsum[1-10]}
\end{Parallel}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is a very valid one, and you have provided a full working example. I've chosen another answer based on elegancy.